# use int as input for GregorianCalendar but am not able to continue scanning JAVA

Tags: java, string

I was trying make an code to input the Date of birth to give back the Day of the week of that day, I used input stream reader to get my input

```
package testing;

import java.io.*;
import java.text.DateFormat;
import java.util.*;

public class theDayYouBorn {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(System.in);
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(isr);

        System.out.println("Please Input the Year You Born at : ");
        int year1 = br.read();
        System.out.println("Thank!, Please input the Month :");
        int month1 = br.read();
        System.out.println("Okay, last thing Please input the day : ");
        int day1 = br.read();

        GregorianCalendar gc = new GregorianCalendar(year1, month1, day1);
        Date d1 = gc.getTime();
        DateFormat df = DateFormat.getDateInstance();
        String sd = df.format(d1);
        String dayName = gc.getDisplayName(gc.DAY_OF_WEEK, gc.LONG,
                Locale.getDefault());
        System.out.println("The Day you born in was a " + sd
                + " and the day was " + dayName);

    }
}
```

it's let me just put the first input and then it's run and a random date without asking for the day or the month

then I try to use String as input and converting them into Integer and it's work... I change this :

```
System.out.println("Please Input the Year You Born at : ");
String year = br.readLine();
System.out.println("Thank!, Please input the Month :");
String preMonth = br.readLine();
System.out.println("Okay, last thing Please input the day : ");
String day = br.readLine();

int day1 = Integer.parseInt(day);
int month2 = Integer.parseInt(preMonth);
int year1 = Integer.parseInt(year);
int month1 = month2 - 1;
```

I was trying to understand why I was not able to scan the integer.

Comment: Please read this: [JavaDoc of `read()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/BufferedReader.html#read%28%29): *Reads a single character.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you take a look at [documentation of `read()` method](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/BufferedReader.html#read--) you will find that:

> Reads a single character.
>
> **Returns**:
> The character read, as an integer in the range 0 to 65535 (0x00-0xffff), or -1 if the end of the stream has been reached

So each call of `read` will return one `char` (or to be more precise its numeric representation in Unicode Table like `'a'` is `97`, or `'1'` is `49`).

For instance, if for below code

```
System.out.println("Please Input the Year You Born at : ");
System.out.println(br.read());
System.out.println(br.read());
System.out.println(br.read());
System.out.println(br.read());
System.out.println(br.read());
System.out.println(br.read());
```

we will provide input `1987`

```
Please Input the Year You Born at : 
1987[here we press enter]
```

on Windows operating system we will end up with

```
49
57
56
55
13
10
```

which represents

```
int -> char
----------- 
49  -> '1'
57  -> '9'
56  -> '8'
55  -> '7'
13  -> '\r'
10  -> '\n'
```

Problem like this doesn't exist in case of `br.readLine();` because its purpose is to read data as text, not as binary data.