# Not asking for second input

Tags: java

**Code:**

```
public class Adddemo {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        int i, j, k;
        System.out.println("enter value of i: ");
        i = (int) System.in.read();
        System.out.println("enter value of j: ");
        j = (int) System.in.read();

        k = i + 1;

        System.out.println("sum is: " + k);
    }
}
```

Is `System.in.read` used for multiple inputs?

Comment: What do you mean? Your question is code-only. What is the behavior you expect, and what does it do instead?

Comment: `k = i + 1` looks wrong to me.

Comment: Not answering the Q you didnt ask, but... k=i+j

Comment: output:
enter value of i: 
5
enter value of j: /*it does not wait for my input for j*/
sum is: 54

Comment: This is an explanation also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15446689/what-is-the-use-of-system-in-read-in-java

Comment: @psychocoder if your problem is it doesn't ask 2nd value then try adding `System.in.read()` before statement `j=System.in.read();`

Comment: Do you just want to add 2 numbers?

Comment: @psychocoder try this http://pastebin.com/Du2Q0f6F

Comment: That is not helping me.

Comment: why not it will ask you second value too

Comment: Similar problem with `read` in `BufferedReader`: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30687153/use-int-as-input-for-gregoriancalendar-but-am-not-able-to-continue-scanning-java

Answer (score 3):

`System.in.read()` is used to read a character.

suppose you enter 12, then `i` becomes `1(49 ASCII)` and `j` becomes `2(50 ASCII)`.

suppose you enter `1` and then press enter, `i` becomes `(ASCII 49)` and `enter(ASCII 10)`, even enter is considered a character and hence skipping your second input.

use a `scanner` or `bufferedReader` instead.

#### Using a scanner

```
Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
int i = sc.nextInt();
int j = sc.nextInt();
int k = i + j; 
System.out.println(k);
```

#### Using a BufferedReader

```
BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
int i = Integer.parseInt(reader.readLine());
int j = Integer.parseInt(reader.readLine());
int k = i + j;
System.out.println(k);
```

Comment: If u print only value of j than it displays 10. and also it doesn't even ask for the input of j... thats confusing to me..

Comment: because 10 is the ASCII value of new line. Please check the [ASCII Table](http://www.asciitable.com/).

Comment: David and Pshemo did the right search, they gave you the right question [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30687153/use-int-as-input-for-gregoriancalendar-but-am-not-able-to-continue-scanning-java).

Comment: @psychocoder you cannot read integer values using `System.in.read()`, you will need some extra help(`Scanner` or `BufferedReader`). Every character is considered an input using `System.in.read()`.

Comment: Yeah. I got it. Thank you. and I will use Scanner instead.

Answer (score 1):

System.in.read() doesn't read a number, it reads one byte and returns its value as an int.

If you enter a digit, you get back 48 + that digit because the digits 0 through 9 have the values 48 through 57 in the ASCII encoding.

To read a number from System.in you should use a Scanner.

Answer (score 0):

use Scanner class instead:

```
 import java.util.Scanner;
 public class Adddemo {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        Scanner read=new Scanner(System.in);
        int i,j,k;
        System.out.println("enter value of i: ");
        i=(int)read.nextInt();
        System.out.println("enter value of j: ");
        j=(int)read.nextInt();

        k=i+1;

        System.out.println("sum is: "+k);
    }    
 }
```

Comment: Yeah, `InputStream.read()` only reads a single byte at a time. If your console is using a multi-byte character encoding (such as UTF-16) then it won't work.

Comment: I want to read the second value. It doesn't even ask for that. And i know Scanner class. I have to use System.in.read().

Comment: @psychocoder `System.in.read()` reads only a single byte. It sounds like you're pressing enter after typing the first number (you shouldn't).

Answer (score 0):

System.in.read()  reads 1 byte at a time. 

if you want to feed your input values for i and j , do this
Leave one space between 1 and 2 while giving input in console
1 will be taken as value for i
2 will be taken as value for j

giving input as 12 (no spaces) will also yield the same result, cuz each byte is considered as an input

```
program
    int i,j;
        char c,d;
        System.out.println("enter value of i: ");
        i=(int)System.in.read();
        System.out.println("enter value of j: ");
        j=(int)System.in.read();

        System.out.println("i is: "+i);
        System.out.println("j is: "+j);

Output:
enter value of i,j: 
1 2          //leave one space 

i is: 1
j is: 2
```

let me know if you didn't understand yet

Comment: commonly we use System.in.read() to read one byte at a time during file read scenarios